# Mostrar un alert en un TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uitableviewcontroller

Quiero mostrar un alert al pulsar un botón que está en un tableviewcell y me da el siguiente error:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is  .

Este es mi código:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CeldaID", for: indexPath) as! ComprarTableViewCell

    cell.nombreEntradaLBL.text = nombreConcierto[indexPath.row]
    cell.comprarEntradaIMG.image = UIImage(named: imagenes[indexPath.row])
    cell.fechaEntradasLBL.text = fechas[indexPath.row]
    cell.comprarBTN.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ComprarTableViewController.mostrarAlerta), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

@objc func mostrarAlerta(){
    let alerta = UIAlertController(title: "Compra satisfactoria", message: "Se han comprado su entrada/as", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alerta.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
    alerta.present(alerta,animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu problema, tal como lo dice el error, es que en esta linea:

```
alerta.present(alerta,animated: true)
```

Estas indicando que al ViewController llamado alerta, presente el Viewcontroller alerta, obviamente esto no se puede, lo correcto seria que el ViewController que contiene la TableView sea el que presente la alerta.

Suponiendo que el metodo mostrarAlerta pertenece al ViewController padre entonces bastaria con presentarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
present(alerta,animated: true)
```